# WPF application plugin using resources from host application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, plugins, staticresource

I've got a similar situation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749256/static-resources-in-wpf-in-pluggable-application) question. However, that users glazes over how they were able to have plugins take advantage of static resources from the host application at run-time. That is my stumbling block.

Lets call the host "K". At the moment I've made a resource dictionary called KResources.xaml where all of the application's resources are held (app.xaml just merges this dictionary and calls it a day).

In my plugin I'm creating a view, V, that needs to use the KResources dictionary. This is what I'm currently trying:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
 <ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/K;component/Resources/KResources.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
 </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Ive also tried the following syntax:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    Source="pack://application:,,,/K;component/Resources/KResources.xaml" />
```

Compilation goes well and my V.xaml file recognizes the resources, but I get an exception at runtime when this view is created:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
HResult=-2146233087
LineNumber=19
LinePosition=8
Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'K.UI.Infrastructure.CaliburnBootstrapper' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '19' and line position '8'.
Source=PresentationFramework
StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
InnerException: 
   HResult=-2147024809
   Message=An item with the same key has already been added.
   Source=mscorlib
   StackTrace:
        at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
        at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
        at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
        at Caliburn.Micro.AssemblySourceCache.<Install>b__4(Type t)
        at Caliburn.Micro.EnumerableExtensions.Apply[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable, Action`1 action)
        at Caliburn.Micro.AssemblySourceCache.<Install>b__0(Object s, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        at Caliburn.Micro.BindableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        at Caliburn.Micro.BindableCollection`1.<>c__DisplayClasse.<AddRange>b__d()
        at Caliburn.Micro.XamlPlatformProvider.OnUIThread(Action action)
        at Caliburn.Micro.BindableCollection`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
        at Caliburn.Micro.BootstrapperBase.StartRuntime()
        at Caliburn.Micro.BootstrapperBase.Initialize()
        at K.UI.Infrastructure.CaliburnBootstrapper..ctor() in C:\Dev\K\source\K.UI\Infrastructure\CaliburnBootstrapper.cs:line 44
```

The line **Message=An item with the same key has already been added.** stands out.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have elements using the same Key name in both dictionaries? Oh and what's on line 19?

Comment: I think line 19 refers to a line within the WpfXamlLoader class. Reference: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Markup/WpfXamlLoader.cs

I'll do a quick audit of my project for keys defined with the same name. Thanks for the suggestion! I'll comment back when I've finished.

Comment: OK I've combed the solution as thoroughly as I think possible (shoutout to Notepad++ and regexr.com for being rad). I found a couple duplicate keys, but they were scoped such that they shouldn't have been colliding. I removed the name duplication anyhow but am still fighting the same, unhelpful exception at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that omitting the Merged dictionary code altogether resulted in the static resources I required being located properly at run-time anyway. The downside is that during design time the IDE highlights them as if they don't exist.

This leaves me at the same point as this question : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749256/static-resources-in-wpf-in-pluggable-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749256/static-resources-in-wpf-in-pluggable-applicationhttp://)